# Separate numbers with comma

Tags: c#

I had a task to display the numbers, which are divided into 3 and 5. I have them are displayed, but it is necessary so that they are output separated by commas.

```
Console.WriteLine("Write number greater than 0: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int n;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out n))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
                        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
                }
            }
```

`String.Join(" , ", i)` doesn't work.

I am very sorry for such a question, but I am a beginner, I looked everywhere, but I did not find it anywhere.
*After the last number should not be a comma.*

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and output? You can't use `i` as the second argument for `String.Join`, it's looking for an array or IEnumerable.

Comment: search for "fizzbuzz" to see several variants to this problem.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, n + 1).Where(i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0).Select(i => i.ToString())));`

Comment: @itsme86 I'm sure OP's teacher would be suspicious of a new programmer using LINQ for such a simple task :)

Comment: Write number greater than 0:
100
3 5 6 9 10 12 15 18 20 21 24 25 27 30 33 35 36 39 40 42 45 48 50 51 54 55 57 60 63 65 66 69 70 72 75 78 80 81 84 85 87 90 93 95 96 99 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Console.Write("{0} ", i);
```

To

```
Console.Write($"{i}, ");
```

Revised to handle trailing comma:

```
        var results = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                results.Add(i);
            }
        }

        Console.Write(string.Join(", ", results));
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: After the last number should not be a comma

Comment: @Antonio99 Try to solve the problem yourself. This answer got you 99% of the way there.

Comment: Rather than outputting straight to the console put the results into a `List<int>` and then you can use `string.Join()` once you have all the results.

Comment: @Antonio99 Then can't you just change your loop to only go up to the second-to-last number, and then write the last number (without a comma) after the loop?

Comment: Or, output the comma before the number, except in the first pass through the loop.

Comment: @Antonio99 `string.join()` used in this way will not add a comma at the end, it will only add the comma between the values. Try it.